# CakePHP 3 Internationalization global

Tags: internationalization, translation, cakephp-3.0

I have a little question with the CakePHP internationalisation. (I haven't found my answer in the doc)

My App is in french and english, so i set the default language to fr_FR.

All my variables with __() are in french.

I have the pot file, and in the folder 'Locale', two subfolder : 'fr_FR' and 'en_US'. The two subfolders have a po file.

But must i create the 'fr_FR' folder and po file ? Is it necessary ? My po file for the french has 0 translation.

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to provide language files for your default locale. The [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html) say

> The __() function will translate the passed string if a translation is
>   available, or return it unmodified

.